# Validate Wocommerce customers before purchase

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I will develop an ecommerce with Woocommerce and I need that not everyone can make a purchase. Instead, users register as customers and once the administrator externally validates that this client is real and allows him to buy. Do you know any plugin or any way to do it?

Comment: Please note that asking for plugin recommendations is off topic in StackOverFlow as it is code oriented.

Answer (score 1):

In woocommerce setting ( Means in admin panel, woocommerce->settings ), you can see a navigation tab at the top where you can see "Accounts & Privacy" tab, click on it and then unchecked 'Allow customers to place orders without an account' checkbox and save.
[image]

Comment: Hello!

But I understand that if the user creates an account he could buy without administrator validation, right?

Greetings,

Comment: Yes, register user can buy product without administrator approve.

Comment: To prevent checkout without approve, you need to add some meta data when user registered, and need to check this metadata when someone trying to checkout. So custom code need to add to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of the following plugins

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-for-logged-users/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-approve-user/

The first one only allows users who are logged in to be able to complete purchases. The second one allows you to manually aprove users who sign up. By combining these two plugins you would be able to solve your issue.